# Set Vim's shiftwidth and tabstop based on directory

Tags: vim, coding-style

I have a project I'm working on currently where the coding standard is to use 2 space indentation. On other projects, however, I use 4 space indentation.

Is there an easy way to tell vim that all files within a certain directory should have a tabstop of 2 spaces?

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7541714) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2564664).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple vim configurations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889602/multiple-vim-configurations)

Comment: @CiroSantilli This question has an accepted answer. Why are you suggesting possible duplicates? Those answers are categorically worse than the accepted answer here.

Comment: Do you agree with that the questions are the same? If yes, we should centralize all information on a single page, and the simplest criterion is choose the oldest question. The other question also wins on number of votes criterion. This question and its answers here will still be useful even if this is marked as a dupe.

Comment: No, I do not believe they are the same. I would not have selected the answer given in the other questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The venerable Tim Pope just released a plugin call [Sleuth](http://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth), which automagically determines shiftwidth and tabstop (among other buffer options) based on what's used in the current file (or, incredibly, if it's a new buffer, based on nearby files).

Answer (score 20):

Use an `autocmd` that matches the directory and sets whatever options you need:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
```

This will apply to files in subdirectories as well.

As Ingo Karkat points out, such commands should use `setlocal` instead of `set` so as to be specific to buffers.

Comment: Make that `:setlocal`, or the settings will also affect other files opened afterwards.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thank you; I forgot about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't worry about a central configuration of those project directory exceptions, the `:autocmd` solution from Nikita Kouevda is simple and effective. On the other hand, if you want the specific configuration stored with the project (and don't want to embed this in all files via modelines), you have the following two options:

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory. You can place the `:set ts=2 sw=2 et` commands in there.

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393).

Comment: This is a good option, but it's probably good practice to use `:set secure` with `:set exrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote plugin exactly for these needs: [Vimprj](http://goo.gl/efUVT). This is a plugin for managing options for different projects.

One guy even wrote [nice article](http://goo.gl/87csV) about it.

Shortly: you need to create `.vimprj` file at the root of your project (or `.vimprj` directory with some `.vim` files), and every time you switch to this project, this file or directory `.vimprj` will be sourced.

Read plugin page for details, and feel free to ask me if you have any problems with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**embear/vim-localvimrc** https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc worked well.

I create a `.lvimrc` file containing:

```
setlocal noexpandtab
setlocal shiftwidth=8
setlocal tabstop=8
```

and it beats the default `autocmd FileType` configurations from my `.vimrc` for every file in a child directory that contains `.lvimrc`.

The plugin sources every `.lvimrc` it finds on a parent directory, root-side first, so that the the deeper the `.lvimrc` the more precedence.

**EditorConfig** https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim is a great option if you control the source tree, for settings which everyone must use, as it contains editor agnostic settings (and a Vim implementation).